# Use Guice SPI to programmatically add InjectionPoint

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I see com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint from google guice SPI.

Is it possible to dynamically add injection point via InjectionPoint class.

If yes what is the best to do this ?

this'll allow adding injection point code on legacy code.

Comment: I guess since `InjectionPoint` is a final class you cannot extend it. Anyway, *any* possible injection point in Java language necessarily reduces down to static/instance method or field or a constructor since these are all of the parts of the class which can interact with external world. It is not possible to say more until you describe exactly what you want.

Comment: In Guice, injection points are defined via @Inject (jsr330 or guice). This is a convention others may use another systems to define those injection points. We could have imagined write down those injection points in simple text files. My question is : from that list can I convert them in guice InjectionPoint to virtually add "@Inject" and that virtual "@Inject" fully understood when creating the injector. My goal is not to extends InjectionPoint but simply use them as SPI element. Hope i'm clearer.

Comment: No, you are not really correct. Injection points is more general concept, see http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ExtendingGuice. It is absolutely possible to inject into fields/constructors not annotated by `@Inject`. For example, default constructor is an injection point (even though it has no dependencies-injectees). Another example is `@InjectLogger` annotation from the official documentation. In fact, via `TypeListener`s you can inject dependencies into virtually any field/method/constructor the class provides. So, `@Inject` is not a definition of injection point.

Comment: Anyway, I believe it is not possible to hook into Guice class creating machinery easily. Basically Guice can create objects either via providers (it delegates object creation to user-defined provider, injecting possible dependencies into the provider) or via constructors, but these constructors must either be annotated with `@Inject` or an explicit constructor binding should be present for the class in question. You can look through the Guice code, it really easy to read and debug.

Comment: So, I guess the closest thing you can get is dynamic construction of modules with constructor bindings (see here http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ToConstructorBindings), constructors for which you must resolve yourself.

Comment: I fully agree with you that injection point is more general that the "@Inject" annotation. jsr330 is just a public way for developpers to declare them compared with what is possible with guice spi. So from what you said me I'll write an answer (TypeListener, ConstructorBinding and I add AOP for method injection).

Comment: The new link to the wiki mentioned by @VladimirMatveev is https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ToConstructorBindings , the old one does not redirect properly